# Parallel downloading a file using command line and lftp

Tags: http, lftp

I am looking into how to use lftp for parallel downloading a file over http .I see this example

```
lftp -c "pget -n 10 http://example.com/foo.bar"
```

However not finding any information on how to specify custom http headers and cookie values here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cookies there is the http:cookie setting. See the man page. Custom headers are not supported yet, but there are a few supported via http:* settings.